# Open closed principle vs Strategy pattern

Tags: design-patterns, solid-principles

I have read both strategy pattern and open closed principle both look same to me.If they are same why we have different name pattern \principle for them.

Please share your thoughts on this one.

Answer (score 7):

OCP comes at a much more general level than Strategy - that's why it is a **principle** rather than a **pattern**. OCP doesn't state that there should be a class X that does Y and Z and collaborates in W way with another class. It only states that *classes should be closed to modification but open for extension*.

You can achieve OCP in a class by externalizing some of its responsibilities to a Strategy and writing new Strategies instead of modifying the class itself, but it is not the only way of respecting OCP. There are other patterns that help achieve OCP, like Abstract Factory.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy pattern has to do with selecting different algorithms at run time. It doesn't say anything about whether or how a class should be modified during maintenance.

The open/closed principle has to do with allowing extensions during maintenance, but not modifications. It doesn't say anything about either implementing or selecting different algorithms at run time.

If these two still look the same to you, I'd suggest you write some code incorporating each pattern. That should make the differences crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

Open-close is a principle which strategy pattern is a good way to implementing that .

Answer (score 0):

I think, design pattern - is like a cure against some disease. 
And disease - is violation of S.O.L.I.D.

One more thing - all Design Patterns compliance S.O.L.I.D principles, and other principles:
Prefer composition to inheritance
Incapsulate changes
Do high cohesion and low coupling
etc

Here some example from http://www.remondo.net/solid-principles-csharp-open-closed/:

> ...This violates the Open / Closed Principle. ... **One way to establish this is by applying the Strategy Pattern** ...